# Detect when song changes in Shoutcast server

Tags: php, regex, shoutcast

I have a script that is reading the last line of a log file for my radio station using the following command.

```
watch -n 1 php script.php
```

That command above executes my script in 1 sec intervals. The log this script is reading has output as listed below.

```
2016-04-28 23:30:34 INFO    [ADMINCGI sid=1] Title updated [Bankroll Fresh Feat. Street Money Boochie - Get It]
2016-04-28 23:30:34 INFO    [ADMINCGI sid=1] DJ name updated [1]
2016-04-28 23:30:36 INFO    [YP] Updating listing details for stream #1 succeeded.
```

Every time the song changes, 3 more lines are added to the logs as in the example output above. I need a way to do 3 things.

1) Detect only the latest occurrance of an entry in the logs matching the pattern of line #1
2) Execute code when that occurs and do nothing else until that happens again.
3) Regex to Extract data between 'second set' of square brackets on a line delimited by a "-" e.g. [Rihanna feat. Keyshia Cole - Title (Remix)]

Before the log output of my radio script changed, my script would detect when a song change occurred by tailing the logs for the 'Title Updated' line and then extract the artist and title name from within the square brackets on that same line.

Once that happens the data is sent to a MySQL database and sent to Twitter.

I have tried using "strpos" within an if statement to first detect a line that contains "Title updated" and then execute a function to grab the song information from the line afterwards which works but only if I use a static scenario by putting an example except of line #1 into a variable and then running it off my script. It does detect the line and server it's purpose but I need my script to remain dynamic meaning to only do something when this event happens and always sit idle in the meantime.

Right now I had to go bootleg and do the following.

Created a function to grab the last 3 lines from the log and then put each line into an array. Going off the example output above.
    array[0] = Target Line
    array[1] = next line
    array[3] = next line

The logs would remain in this fashion as no other output is posted until the next song change and then it repeats with the only thing changing is the Artist and Title information. Currently since I am running my script to forcibly look at array[0] which is always the line I need, when it the script posts to Twitter on a song change, it immediately sends duplicates. Luckily I implemented error codes into the Twitter portion so that I can use sleep() to force my script to idle for 180 seconds (3 minutes) around the average song length. Now this is decent and it does post but my Tweets are no longer in real time because each song has different lengths.

Here is a snippet from my script below...

```
$lines = read_file(TEXT_FILE, LINES_COUNT);
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $pattern="/\[([^\]]*)\]/";
            if (preg_match_all($pattern, $lines[0], $matches)){
                foreach ($matches[1] as $a ){

     $fulltitle = explode("-", $matches[1][1]);

     $artist = $fulltitle[0];
     $title = $fulltitle[1];
```

This script below is the direction I would like to go back to and does work when using the static version as in the example below. Soon as I set the script to look at the last line of the log it never detects a change due to it always detecting the next line after the target line. (believe regex may be responsible but not sure)

```
$line ="2016-04-27 22:56:48     INFO    [ADMINCGI sid=1] Title updated [Tessa Feat. Gucci Mane - Get You Right]";
echo $line;

$pattern="/\[([^\]]*)\]/";

$needle = " Title updated ";
if (strpos($line,$needle) !== false) {
    preg_match_all($pattern, $line, $matches);
        foreach ($matches[1] as $a ){

$fulltitle = explode("-", $matches[1][1]);

$artist = $fulltitle[0];
$title = $fulltitle[1];
```